# $\lim_{h\to0} \frac{\sqrt[3]{x+h+3}-\sqrt[3]{x+3}}{h}\;?$

Tags: calculus, limits

What is the fraction that have to multiply to calculate the limit

$$\lim_{h\to0} \frac{\sqrt[3]{x+h+3}-\sqrt[3]{x+3}}{h}\;?$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)\implies a-b=\frac{a^3-b^3}{a^2+ab+b^2}$$

and put $\;a=\sqrt[3]{x+h+3}\;,\;\;b=\sqrt[3]{x+3}\;$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Since $h$ is small, what you can also do is to write $$\sqrt[3]{x+h+3}=\sqrt[3]{x+3}\sqrt[3]{1+\frac{h}{x+3}}$$ Now remember that, if $y$ is small $(1+y)^a\simeq 1+a y$. So,$$\sqrt[3]{x+h+3}=\sqrt[3]{x+3}\sqrt[3]{1+\frac{h}{x+3}}\simeq \sqrt[3]{x+3}\Big(1+\frac{h}{3(x+3)}\Big) $$

I am sure that you can take from here.